# What Android OS version is on the Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire-hd

Which version of Android is running on the recently announced Kindle Fire HD, Amazon seems to fail to mention that detail in the specifications they list for [Kindle Fire HD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0083PWAPW)

Comment: CyanogenMod 10 (as soon as it's hackable) ;-) currently http://es.engadget.com/2012/09/07/kindle-fire-hd-ics

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Amazon confirms Kindle Fire HD models use Android 4.0 under the hood](http://www.engadget.com/2012/09/06/amazon-confirms-kindle-fire-hd-models-use-android-4-0/).

Comment: ups ... you beat me to it! +1

Answer (score 8):

By [this comparison](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-57507776-251/kindle-fire-hd-vs-nexus-7-which-one-is-right-for-you/) between Kindle Fire HD 7" and Nexus 7 done by CNET, it uses a **custom Android 4.0 version**.

<sup>Scroll down to the comparison table to see it</sup>

From the [official product page](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0083PWAWU/ref=amb_link_1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=gateway-center-column&pf_rd_r=0ZR13K3QGGTBSJH0X7V6&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=324600507&pf_rd_i=468294), there's no corroborating information about it.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon confirms ICS is running the Kindle Fire HD. For more infos follow this 
[blogpost](http://androidcommunity.com/amazon-confirms-ics-is-running-the-kindle-fire-hd-20120906/)